# Connect to a proxy server but only from specific interface (eth0)

Tags: raspbian, networking, wifi, ethernet

I want to connect my Raspberry Pi to the university network. I was successful to connect it to [eduroam](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eduroam) (WLAN). Some times I would also like to access the universities network over LAN. For doing so, I need to connect to a proxy server to have access to internet. Also this is working fine with adding the following text to `/etc/profile.d/proxy.sh`:

```
export http_proxy=**proxyserverURL**
export https_proxy=**proxyserverURL**
export ftp_proxy=**proxyserverURL**

export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
export HTTPS_PROXY=$https_proxy
export FTP_PROXY=$ftp_proxy`
```

This will set environment variables for the proxy server and the internet is working over ethernet.

Now the problem is, that if I am only connected to WLAN, it tries to connect to the above defined proxy server, which is not accessible in the eduroam network.

Is there a way to define a proxy only for a specific interface?